# Cannot read property 'map'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to return some data from a headless CMS (Sanity.io) but keep bumping into errors with my React. I've followed this [example](https://github.com/sanity-io/example-frontend-next-js/blob/master/pages/people.js) but now have the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

My code

```
import * as React from "react";
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";
import { Container, Row } from "reactstrap";
const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: "<redacted>",
  dataset: "<redacted>",
  useCdn: true 
});
let dataHenter;
const query = `*[_type == "land"]`;

export default class CountryList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      country: []
    };
  }

  static async getInitialProps() {
    return {
      country: await client.fetch(query)
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { country } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <div className="country">
          <ul className="list">
            {country.map(country => (
              <li key={country._id}>
                <Row>
                  <a>
                    {country.image}
                    <h3>{country.name}</h3>
                  </a>
                </Row>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: make sure 'country' is an array while you use country.map() function on it

Comment: I got it to run by switching my const to "    const { country = [] } = this.props;" 

It is an array that I fetch from Sanity.io. however nothing is shown so the map still fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your component is being rendered, it's possible to country be undefined or null. Make sure it to be array at initial render:

```
const { country } = this.props || { country: [] };
```

Or, with

```
const { country } = this.props;
```

You may use map with country like this:

```
{country && country.length && country.map(country => (
```

This will ensure to run map only when there's country.