# React map function works, but when API called it breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a React bookshelf project, and currently working on the search feature, the app lists the books fine, but when I search the code below breaks, why is this saying it is undefined when I try to search?

Project / code listed [here](https://github.com/3noki/project_5_react_bookshelf_app/tree/master/src)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Books.render
src/utils/Books.js:15

  14 |   <ol className="books-grid">
> 15 |         {this.props.books.map((book) => (
  16 |           <li key={book.id}>
  17 |           <div className='book'>
  18 |             <div className='book-top'>
```

Comment: It is probably undefined in the first render or the component in question. This usually happens if component gets the books from the api on CDM method. You can either move the api call to the componentWillMount method or do a conditional render if this prop exists like in @bradey-whitlock answer. Preferably do both, or return null if books don't exist to block rendering of that component before the rest of the component render code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'map'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862360/cannot-read-property-map)

Comment: Also, I'm surprised to see you didn't find any: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=react+Cannot+read+property+%27map%27+of+undefined

Answer (score 4):

This seems like books is undefined. You could console it out to make sure it's not. You can also put a check before the map like this

```
<ol className="books-grid">
    {this.props.books && this.props.books.map((book) => (
     <li key={book.id}>
     <div className='book'>
      <div className='book-top'>
```